# get remote notification type enabled on iOS 8

Tags: ios, push-notification

in iOS 7 i can retrieve the notification type that the user have enabled in this way:

```
NSUInteger rntypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

but on iOS 8 i can't do this, because i get this in the console:

```
enabledRemoteNotificationTypes is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later.
```

i have found a way to check if the notification are enabled on iOS 8:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]
```

but how i can retrieve of what type of notification are enabled like in iOS 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to developer.apple.com you may use this UIApplication's method:

```
- (UIUserNotificationSettings *)currentUserNotificationSettings
```

and then check notification types by using:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIUserNotificationType types;
```

So it will be something like this:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
UIUserNotificationType types = settings.types;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found out that the types property is basically a bitmask. Here is how you can extract the informations.
My example is in Swift though.

```
    let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()

    if settings.types.rawValue & UIUserNotificationType.Alert.rawValue == UIUserNotificationType.Alert.rawValue
    {
       // can receive alert!
    }
    else
    {
       // if the user is not even able to receive alerts, show him a hint on how to reenable notifications in system settings
    }

    if settings.types.rawValue & UIUserNotificationType.Badge.rawValue == UIUserNotificationType.Badge.rawValue
    {
        // can receive badge!
    }
    if settings.types.rawValue & UIUserNotificationType.Sound.rawValue == UIUserNotificationType.Sound.rawValue
    {
        // can receive sound!
    }
```